# Add condition only if data exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add a condition to the `WHERE` clause ONLY if a variable has data.

I tried with the following `case` statement, but it has a syntax error.

```
Declare @last_name varchar(10) = null;
Select * from TABLE1 
Where FirstName = 'John'
AND CASE WHEN @last_name IS NOT NULL THEN LastName = @last_name
```

Comment: It's a case expression you're using, not a case statement!

Answer (score 5):

```
Select * from TABLE1 
where FirstName = 'John'
  AND (@last_name IS NULL OR LastName = @last_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already posted better ways to write the logic you are trying to express, but just in case you need to use the `CASE` syntax in the future, remember that the syntax requires you to include the word `END`.  This tells SQL where the expression finishes.

This is what a basic `CASE` expression would look like:

```
CASE 
    WHEN MyField = 'MyValue' THEN 'MyResult'
    WHEN MyField = 'MyOtherValue' THEN 'MyOtherResult'
    ELSE 'NoResult'
  END
```

Any CASE expression must have at least the `CASE`, `WHEN`, `THEN`, and `END`.  The `ELSE` isn't strictly necessary - just be aware that if you don't include it, then the expression will return a `NULL` if none of the `WHEN` conditions are met.

Comment: Heh ... thanks, I'll edit. Serves me right for not being specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
Declare @last_name varchar(10) = null;
Select * from TABLE1 
Where FirstName = 'John'
AND LastName = ISNULL(@last_name, LastName)
```

You can also replace ISNULL with COALESCE too.

Comment: What if LastName column is NULL?

Comment: It does not impact the query result, unless you want to put NULL into @last_name and want to find the NULL lastnames. for this issue, you can change the where part of query as follow:Where FirstName = 'John'
AND ISNULL(LastName,'') = ISNULL(@last_name, ISNULL(LastName,''))